# Should I delete this bad question by self or just put it as a negative example for everyone?

Tags: discussion

Should I delete this bad question by self or just put it as a negative example for everyone?

[What is meaning of "DA" in English version of Japanese manga?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58355/what-is-meaning-of-da-in-english-version-of-japanese-manga)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent what you may or should not do is already hard-wired into the site (as what you can or cannot do).

For your question, it doesn't actually matter much — unless it gathers upvotes, it will be [auto-deleted](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) in a couple of days. Closed questions are only kept if they have a positive score or if they have an answer with a positive score.

So, unless there is some positive contribution (in terms of question/answer score = upvotes minus downvotes) on a question, it will not be kept as a "negative example".